# MTU setting in my router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, mtu

I've reset my router (after changing the home gateway to fully bridged mode) and want to know - can I manually set the MTU in the router to 1500 (and / or play around with smaller values if 1500 doesn't resolve the issue)?
It's currently set to 1492 - not sure where that magic number came from (1500 - 8 bytes for PPPoE header?).
One device that is connecting wirelessly to the router doesn't like the way the MTU is now being handled, whereas previously it was happy (it's now complaining that my router 'doesn't support IP packet fragmentation').

Comment: Your ISP will know the correct MTU setting; contact them and ask for it.

Comment: Yep, 1492 is 1500 - 8 byte ppoe header.  You can try to set the MTU to less than 1492.  Try 1464

Comment: Thanks. I found a 'Ping Test to determine Optimal MTU Size on Router'.  http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/19863/~/ping-test-to-determine-optimal-mtu-size-on-router.  Is this correct in general?  In my case, it gives .... 1492!  Should I try a different approach to manage the cranky device (a PS4, oh the joys of parenting).

Comment: It's possible that my setup is fine and the problem is at Sony's end - it appears a lot of playstation users are suddenly having the problem without having changed their home network at all. Joy is us.

Comment: `'doesn't support IP packet fragmentation'` is **normal** for PS4, reboot it and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Problem magically resolved this morning - looks like bob is right (though I'd never noticed the message before myself).